# how to find number of duplicate element in Binary search tree

Tags: c#, data-structures

```
  public void duplicate()
    {
        int repeatation = 0;
        Node current = root;
        Node duplicate = root;
        while (current == null)
        {
            if (duplicate == current || duplicate == current.right  ||  duplicate== current.left)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("node is repeated :" + duplicate);
                repeatation++;



            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("number of repeatation is :"  + repeatation);

    }
```

this code is for duplicate elements in binary search tree and how many time a element repeat but its not working properly ,would you tell me whats wrong with this code and i am not sure i code it right or not......

Comment: No, It's not. all I see is an infinite loop - the object you're checking (current) does not change between the iterations.

Comment: so  how to sort out this problem?? as i mentioned that i tried to sort but couldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that might help you with this issue:

1) Get the maximum value in your BST (just go right, right, ..., right until you reach a leaf)

2) follow this pseudo code:

```
for i = 0 to MAX_VALUE do
  currentNode = root;
  while(TRUE)
      if (currentNode.Value == i)
           apprearanceCount++;
      if (i > currentNode.Value)
           currentNode = currentNode.RightNode;
      else 
           currentNode = currentNode.LeftNode;
      if currentNode == NULL then break; // Don't forget to save appearance count
```

Answer (score 8):

If you traverse the tree [InOrder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Inorder_Traversal) you'll get the repeated elements together, so you just need to check when a value equals the previous, and how many times this happens.

Comment: yeah i did  InOrder traverse and got repeated element

Answer (score 0):

You can just traverse your BST once saving every element in a hash-map along with a counter of how many times you have encountered that element.

After that, iterate through your hash-map and output every element that has a counter greater than 1.

Time complexity: O(n)